# What does it mean to "downcast" a numeric type in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, types, terminology, downcast

From the comments, I'm realizing this question stems from the fact I only code in python, which is dynamically-typed so I've never had to deal with this.

I'm seeing "downcast" used with regard to the altering of a `pandas.DataFrame` column-type, from float64 `==>` float32. Now...I mean...I think I get the "down" part since `64 > 64/2`, but I still don't think I get it completely.

What does "downcast" mean, specifically?

Comment: `float32` is not a subtype of `float64`, therefore it's not downcasting, it's coercion / type conversion. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: lol K well clearly I don't get it. What does downcasting mean?

Comment: I don't know. Python is not statically typed. Does it mean anything at all in Python? I think it's just type coercion / conversion, but some people name it "casting", because it looks syntactically similar to type casting from statically typed languages.

Comment: ah so this has to do with pandas DataFrames which use `numpy.dtype`s to represent their field-values. You can do a Ctrl + F, & search for 'downcast' in this article: https://www.dataquest.io/blog/pandas-big-data/

Comment: @AndreyTyukin This terminology is used in the Pandas docs. See [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Python does not have a static type system, the term *[downcasting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting)* became free, and is now used in Pandas documentation synonymously with *[type coercion](https://tapestry.apache.org/type-coercion.html)*.